# Flutter JSON encode raw string

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this json data that contains strings `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (new line) - It's from Firebase. The problem is when I encode the data using `json.encode` it add an escaping character. So `\r` becomes `\\r`.
I'm sending that data to an another server.
`json.encode` works as expected if I do `json.encode({'hello': 'world\r\n'})` but it adds `\` when I used it on my other string.

Am I missing something?
Is there some type of encoding to prevent it from adding `\`?

Comment: It sounds like your JSON data does not contain carriage return and newline characters but contains the literal character sequences '\', 'r' and '\', 'n'.

Comment: It does contains character literal since Firebase only support that. Would a replace all \r with \r do the trick?

Comment: what is the problem with the escaped JSON data? When you decode it'll be removed automatically. There is no such harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the data you received does not contain CR and LF characters but contains their escape sequences (`\` followed by `r` and `\` followed by `n`).  Therefore when you encode that to JSON, it will be escaped again.

You could do:

```dart
data = data.replaceAll('\\r', '\r').replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
```

which probably would work most of the time, but it would have the corner case of undesirably replacing occurrences that were explicitly intended to be escaped. (That is, a string `'\\n'` would be transformed to a sequence `\`, LF.)

Since the data is already escaped, you probably could unescape it with `json.decode`.  Of course, decoding the data as JSON just to re-encode it to JSON seems a little silly, so if it's already properly encoded JSON, you ideally should pass it through it unchanged.